# Material Design Lite form button doesn't submit anything

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite, http-request

I am rather new to CSS and might miss some basic thing. I get the code for HTML form from tutorial site for Material Design Lite but it doesn't send any HTTP request.

What do I miss?

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Acme Co.</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                <form action="foo.html">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="username" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Username</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="userpass" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Password</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include the links in the `<head>`?

Comment: Yes, I use <head> and include the link to css for MDL.

Comment: Please include that in your example

Answer (score 2):

Put your `<Button>` inside `<form></form>` tag.

Like this:

```html
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Acme Co.</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                <form action="foo.html">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="username" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Username</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="userpass" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" type="submit" name="login">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: It also completely messes up layout. It appears that MDL is more aimed towards mobile phones where you touch submit button, opposed to hitting "enter" while being focused on password input field, otherwise there would have been css styles which fixes this issue.

Comment: That damn button was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>`use this, you are using a simple button, but a php form accepts a submit type button with an action.

Answer (score -6):

I think you got wrong 100%.

Why?

HTML, CSS and JavaScript can't send HTTP Request.

You can use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), [PHP](https://secure.php.net/) or every programming language that can send HTTP request you want.

Comment: Ajax is javascript

Comment: Yes, anyway Ajax can send HTTP Request. I edited the answer anyway.